# How can I know text file is empty or not?(in C)

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to detect text file is empty or not in C.
(values are initialized in NULL)
Whenever read first in value(using fscanf), it always returns file has zero,
even if it has value "0" or "empty".

How can I know the target text file is empty or not?
(it should be distinguished even it has "0" in first letter)

Comment: Should be EOF, right?

Comment: Check if the file size is zero?

Comment: Also, it would help if you could tell us what you're actually *doing*! Preferably by creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also include the actual contents of the file, if there is any. And lastly please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: A text file contains characters which are **integers** in C. `NULL` is a macro with a _null **pointer** constant_. => A text file cannot contain `NULL`!

Comment: @ChandanaKumara: Tip: C is not C++.

Comment: @Bodo Thiesen:  I removed Duplicate flag. But I think it may duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file was successfully open for read, as per `fopen(filename, "r")`, you can verify if it is empty before any read operation this way:

```
int is_empty_file(FILE *fp) {
    int c = getc(fp);
    if (c == EOF)
        return 1;
    ungetc(c, fp);
    return 0;
}
```

`ungetc()` is guaranteed to work for at least one character.  The above function will return `1` if the file is empty or if it cannot be read, due to an I/O error.  You can tell which by testing `ferr(fp)` or `feof(fp)`.

If the file is a stream associated to a device or a terminal, the test code will block until at least one byte can be read, or end of file is signaled.

If the file is a regular file, you could also use a system specific API to determine the file size, such as `stat`, `lstat`, `fstat` (on Posix systems).

Answer (score 1):

If you're under Linux, you can use [`stat` or `fstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
int fstat(int fd, struct stat *buf);
int lstat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

Will give you this information:

```
struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
    ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
    mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
    nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
    uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
    gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
    dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
    time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
    time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
    time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

To check for the size using `stat`:

```
struct stat info;

if(stat(filepath, &info) < 0) {
    /* error */
}

if(info.st_size == 0) { 
    /* file is empty */
}
```

Or using `fstat`:

```
int fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY);
struct stat info;

if(fstat(fd, &info) < 0) {
    /* error */
}

if(info.st_size == 0) { 
    /* file is empty */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do using `ftell`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_file_size (char *filename) {
   FILE *fp;
   int len;

   fp = fopen(filename, "r");
   if( fp == NULL )  {
      perror ("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

   len = ftell(fp);
   fclose(fp);

   return(len);
}
```

Comment: 3 problems: `ftell()` might not return the file size on text streams, it might fail on streams where seeking is not supported such as the terminal, and it might return `0` if type `int` is too small for the actual file size, for example if the file is exactly 4GB.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, It has limitations. but it still satisfy the answer as asker wanted to know the file has some data or not. Didn't assume these cases. Thanks for pointing out.